# How to add bulk users ( using a csv file ) to an AzureDevops Group using Powershell or other cli tool

Tags: azure-devops

I need to add a long list of users to a new created azure devops group.

It seems that devops cli does not have this kind of functionality

When I run the following script I get the error Invoke-RestMethod:Page Not Found:   and I cannot get any solution for it

can it be a permission-issue ?

Has anyone done this kind of bulk assignment do azure devops group?

```
# Your Azure DevOps organization and PAT
$organization = "xyz"
$personalAccessToken = "xyz"
$apiUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis"

# Group name to add users to
$groupName = "xyz"

# Path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = Resolve-Path "/ test.csv"

# Base64-encode the Personal Access Token and add it to the headers
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}

# Function to add a user to a group
function Add-UserToGroup {
    param (
        [string]$userDescriptor,
        [string]$groupDescriptor
    )

    $body = @{ principalDescriptor = $userDescriptor } | ConvertTo-Json
    $url = "$apiUrl/groupentitlements/$groupDescriptor/members"

    # Send the request
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -Headers $headers -ContentType "application/json"
    return $response
}

# Get the descriptor of the group
$groupsUrl = "$apiUrl/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
$group = $groups.value | Where-Object { $_.principalName -eq $groupName }
$groupDescriptor = $group.descriptor

# Import the user list from the CSV
$users = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

# Loop through each user and add them to the group
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userEmail = $user.UserName
    $userDescriptorUrl = "$apiUrl/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1&subjectTypes=user&mailAddress=$userEmail"
    $userDescriptorObject = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userDescriptorUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
    $userDescriptor = $userDescriptorObject.value.descriptor

    if ($userDescriptor) {
        Add-UserToGroup -userDescriptor $userDescriptor -groupDescriptor $groupDescriptor
        Write-Host "Added user ($userEmail) to group ($groupName)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Could not find user descriptor for email ($userEmail)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The '**`POST`**' method API you are using in the '**`Add-UserToGroup`**' function is not the right one. It is not ever stated within the documentation of "[**Member Entitlement Management API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)".

To add a member to a Group, you should use the '**`PUT`**' method API "[**Members - Add**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)" that has stated in the documentation. This API add only one member every time, so, as you have been trying, you need to use a loop to read each member from the list of all users and add that member into the group using the API.

---

**EDIT:**

From the PowerShell script you provided:

```
$apiUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis"
. . .
$groupsUrl = "$apiUrl/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
```

Can see the HTTP URI you are using to list groups is like as below.

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

The prefix "**`https://vsaex.dev.azure.com`**" is not right for this API HTTP URL. The right prefix should be "**`https://vssps.dev.azure.com`**".

- To list groups within an Azure DevOps organization, you can use the API "[**Groups - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)".

  ```
  GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=7.0-preview.1
  ```
- To get a specified group within an Azure DevOps organization, you can use the API "[**Groups - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)" with the descriptor of that group.

  ```
  GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups/{groupDescriptor}?api-version=7.0-preview.1
  ```

From the response of above API, you can get the **`groupId`** (**`originId`**) of the groups.

In addition, for the **`memberId`** on the API "[**Members - Add**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)", it should be the **`userId`** of the user. To get the ID of a user within an Azure DevOps organization, you can use the API "[**Identities - Read Identities**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#by-email)" with the Email of that user.

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/identities?searchFilter=General&filterValue={email}&queryMembership=None&api-version=7.0
```

---

Comment: Thank you! I edited the function, but still no luck https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78223243/how-to-add-bulk-users-using-a-csv-file-to-an-azuredevops-group-using-powersh

Comment: @MyADOObsession, Provide the edited PowerShell script.

Comment: in this new thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78223243/how-to-add-bulk-users-using-a-csv-file-to-an-azuredevops-group-using-powersh

Comment: @MyADOObsession, I have updated my above answer with more information and suggestions (see **EDIT**).

Comment: thank you for your help, I will test it and let you know