# How to add bulk users ( using a csv file ) to an AzureDevops Group using Powershell

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I need to add a long list of users to a new created azure devops group.

When I run the following script I get the error :

PS /Users/myuser # Get the descriptor of the group
PS /Users/myuser> $groupsUrl = "$apiUrl/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
PS /Users/myuser> $groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
Invoke-RestMethod:   Page Not Found

my code:

```
# Your Azure DevOps organization and PAT
$organization = " "
$personalAccessToken = " "
$apiUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis"

# Group name to add users to
$groupName = "  "

# Path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = Resolve-Path "/Users/ /test.csv"

# Base64-encode the Personal Access Token and add it to the headers
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}

# Function to add a user to a group
function Add-UserToAzureDevOpsGroup {
    param(
        [string]$organization,
        [string]$groupId,
        [string]$memberId,
        [string]$pat
    )

    $uri = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/GroupEntitlements/$groupId/members/$memberId?api-version=7.0"

    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat"))

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} -ContentType "application/json"
}

# Get the descriptor of the group
$groupsUrl = "$apiUrl/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
$group = $groups.value | Where-Object { $_.principalName -eq $groupName }
$groupDescriptor = $group.descriptor

# Import the user list from the CSV
$users = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

# Loop through each user and add them to the group
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userEmail = $user.UserName
    $userDescriptorUrl = "$apiUrl/graph/users?api-version=6.0-preview.1&subjectTypes=user&mailAddress=$userEmail"
    $userDescriptorObject = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userDescriptorUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
    $userDescriptor = $userDescriptorObject.value.descriptor

    if ($userDescriptor) {
        Add-UserToGroup -userDescriptor $userDescriptor -groupDescriptor $groupDescriptor
        Write-Host "Added user ($userEmail) to group ($groupName)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Could not find user descriptor for email ($userEmail)"
    }
}
```

the above code explains

Comment: You are using rest api [Members - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) in the function, it requires `groupid` and `memberid` NOT groupDescriptor and userDescriptor. I fixed the code and add the details below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the incorrect `$apiUrl`, for [user list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) rest api, the  url should be started with `https://vssps.dev.azure.com`, not `https://vsaex.dev.azure.com`. In addition, there are other syntax errors in your script.

You are using [Members - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) rest api to add the user to the group, it requires `groupid` and `memberid`, it's NOT `groupDescriptor` and `userDescriptor`.

[image]

You need to change the rest api used.

1. Use rest api [Member Entitlements - Search Member Entitlements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/member-entitlements/search-member-entitlements?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the memberid.
2. Use rest api [Groups - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the groupid.

I edited your script, and it's working on my side.

```
# Your Azure DevOps organization and PAT
$organization = "orgname"
$personalAccessToken = "PAT"

# Group name to add users to
$groupName = "[orgname]\TestGroup1"

# Path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = Resolve-Path "/Users/tester1/test.csv"

# Base64-encode the Personal Access Token and add it to the headers
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
}

# Function to add a user to a group
function Add-UserToAzureDevOpsGroup {
    param(
        [string]$organization,
        [string]$groupId,
        [string]$memberId,
        [string]$pat
    )

    $uri = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/GroupEntitlements/$groupId/members/$memberId" + "?api-version=7.0"

    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$pat"))

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic $base64AuthInfo")} -ContentType "application/json"
}

# Get the groupid of the group
$groupsUrl = "https://vssps.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
$groups = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $groupsUrl -Method Get -Headers $headers
$group = $groups.value | Where-Object { $_.principalName -eq $groupName }
$groupid = $group.originId
echo $groupid    # check groupid

# Import the user list from the CSV
$users = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

# Loop through each user and add them to the group
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userEmail = $user.UserName
    $memberuri = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/memberentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
    $MemberEntitlements = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers
    $User = $MemberEntitlements.items | Where-Object { $_.member.mailAddress -eq $userEmail }
    $memberId = $User.id

    echo $memberId      # check memberid 

    if ($memberId) {
        Add-UserToAzureDevOpsGroup -organization $organization -groupId $groupid -memberId $memberId -pat $personalAccessToken
        Write-Host "Added user ($userEmail) to group ($groupName)"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Could not find user descriptor for email ($userEmail)"
    }
}
```

My test.csv:

[image]

Execution result:

[image]

The DevOps User added in the group:
[image]